Relative path of Parent Component is added to asset path when page is reloaded
So I have Ng routing for Angular18 configured as below for app.routes.ts which is default routing
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '',component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard',loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.routes').then(m => m.routes)}];

and child routing which is dashboard.routes.ts is configured as below:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { EventsComponent } from './components/events/events.component';
import { EventQuestionsComponent } from './components/events/eventQuestions/eventQuestions.component';
import { StatsComponent } from './components/stats/stats.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '',component: DashboardComponent, children : [
            { path: '',component: StatsComponent },
            { path: 'events',component: EventsComponent },
            { path: 'event-questions/:id',component: EventQuestionsComponent },
        ] 
    }
];

All works fine untill I follow normal flow which is:

localhost/ - Login Page
localhost/dashboard - Default Dashboard Page
localhost/dashboard/events - Dashboard Events Page

But once I visit reload the page on Dashboard Event Page, I get below error and get white screen :
Loading module from “http://localhost/dashboard/main.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
and same issue is faced by all assets, which is that '/dashboard/' is added to all assets paths.
But If I visit '/dashboard/' it loads fine.
I am trying to figure out why /dashboard/ is getting appended to all paths, when child paths are loaded.

please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated, or a github repo where the issue happens

I had the same problem.
Basically, you should carefully check the server.ts file, which intercepts the requests and calls the CommonEngine that handles the rendering of the Angular app.
I believe you will notice that the file you are referring to is returned as index.html.
To solve this problem, I personally had to intercept the sub-paths relative to the root (in your case, "/dashboard") in server.js and redirect them to the root or wherever the static files are located.

But SSR is disabled in my application.

if you are not using an angular ssr,
It could probably be a wrong configuration of the routes on the BE system that exposes the static resources.
Sometimes it can happen that if by mistake in the static exposure system (such as node js or nginx) a path like "**" could have been created that intercepts all the unspecified calls.
The latter could have been configured with the rendering of the index.html file.
This would explain why the MIME type of the call to the Javascript static resource goes wrong

Issue lied somewhere else only, I had copied boilerplate for index.html file from another project of mine , which didn't have <base href='/'>. Once I added that, it started work as fine as possible.
